# I want to create certain number of html pages dynamically with different content some similar content same layou using php, .net or any other method

Tags: php, html, .net, dynamic

can anyone help me in this situation dat

i want to create around 1000 html pages with same layout and different content and some similar content like header, footer, menu and a paragraph in body with some changing values like page title , meta tag , name of file, breacrumb etc should be taken from database .

Comment: what have you tried?? and what do you expect for your question??
all i can say is, Learn a server side language, store the data in the DB. Fetch them to the page. In PHP, it is easy to just include headers and footers

Answer (score 0):

As far as understand your problem you want to create 1000 pages with same layout but different cases.

I have done this earlier.If you can handle the tons of code in single file the you don't have to create 1000 pages. Only One single page is enough.

You can follow the concept of [Query Strings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HofYfGbmg88).

Assign links in your page as

```
 <a href='services.php?id=services'>Services</a>
   <a href='services.php?id=mail'>Mail</a>
```

and handle it like this

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['id']))
   {
       if($_GET['id']=='services')
           {
              //display the content of services
           }
      else if($_GET['id']=='mail')
          {
               //display contents of mail
           }
   }

   ?>
```

First You decide the layout. Then Where The content should be changed use this code. All other layout will be unaffected only the code inside if condition changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many web development frameworks that would support what you are looking for.  Based on what you described, you could achieve it without any programming by using a content management system like Wordpress.  Or if you are interested in building your own, then you could start with ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails, or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a content management system (CMS). Usually you will define a master page template and dynamically generate the other pages from data.

The following site gives a good overview of features sorted by technology:
http://www.cmsmatrix.org/